Kotlin beginner cannot get Response object shape right
I am brand new Kotlin. I am trying to recreate this response object
 Response:
 {"
     id":"abc123",
     "cat1": {
         "key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"
     },
     "cat2": {
         "key3":"value3"
     }
 }

but this does not appear to be possible when creating a data class
val id: String,
val category: String, Map<String, String>

This is what I have so far:
 data class ResponseObject(
     val id: String,
     val category: Map<Category, Map<String, String>>
 )

** Category is an enum class **
I get this
 {"
     id":"abc123",
     "category: {
         "cat1": {
           "key1":"value1",
           "key2":"value2"
         },
         "cat2": {
           "key3":"value3"
         }
     }

}
Any help is appreciated!

cat1 and cat2 are two different properties in your response. But, your data class defines differently.

I think you mean Scope is an enum class?

Maybe this:
import com.google.gson.Gson

data class ResponseObject(val id:String, val cat1:Map<String,String>, val cat2:Map<String,String>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val cat1 = mapOf<String,String>(Pair("key1", "value1"), Pair("key2", "value2"))
    val cat2 = mapOf<String,String>(Pair("key3", "value3"))
    val obj = ResponseObject("abc123", cat1, cat2)

    val g = Gson()
    val json = g.toJson(obj)

    println(json)

}

prints:
{"id":"abc123","cat1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},"cat2":{"key3":"value3"}}
Which when un-minified is this:
{
    "id":"abc123",
    "cat1":{
         "key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"
    },
    "cat2":{
        "key3":"value3"
    }
}


I think you are confusing the idea of a JSON with that of a Map. In a Map, you can not have a conflict of keys. Your JSON will allow the following response
 {
     "id":"abc123",
     "cat1": {
         "key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"
     },
     "cat1": {
         "key3":"value3"
     }
 }

In the above JSON example, "cat1" appears twice, but a map would not allow this.
You can use a JSON serializer library like GSON or Moshi(kotlin friendly) with a few change in your JSON.
 {
     "id":"abc123",
     "categories": [
          [
               "value1", "value2", "value3"
          ],
          [
               "value3", "value4", "value6"
          ]
     ]
 }

With the changed JSON, your response data structure would look like this:
data class ResponseObject(
     val id: String,
     val categories: List<List<String>>
)

OR, A bit more refined and Kotlin-ish way to do this would be
data class ResponseObject(
    val id: String,
    val categories: List<Category>
)

data class Category(
    val name: String,
    val keys: List<CategoryKeyValue>
)

data class CategoryKeyValue(
    val key: String,
    val value: String
)


// JSON Response example 
{
    "id": "abcd123",
    "categories": [
        {
            "name": "cat1",
            "keys": [
                {
                    "key": "key1",
                    "value": "value1"
                },
                {
                    "key": "key2",
                    "value": "value2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "cat2",
            "keys": [
                {
                    "key": "key1",
                    "value": "value1"
                },
                {
                    "key": "key2",
                    "value": "value2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

OR, you can also use something like an ObjectMapper with Jackson Library that forces all JSONs to a Map.
I am linking another stack overflow question for your reference. Here the keys are dynamic. I believe this is something similar to what you are looking for.
Using GSON to parse a JSON with dynamic "key" and "value" in android
Hope this helps you solve your problem.
Edit:

Added another approach that is a lot of typing but cleaner in general.

